# Persist a version number to existing Redux stores in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I would like to be able to load a new bundle in a production React/Redux application that has a different state tree and accommodates users that are already logged in. I'd like to do this by prompting those users to logout so that I can reset the state tree.

**My Approach**

---

By passing down a version from Node, I could configure the store to insert a `version: {latest: VERSION, current: null}` key into a state tree with (or without) a version key. I could "hijack" this into the state tree when I load the users existing state from local storage (would only occur when user reconnects to Node server).

```
const {VERSION} = process.env;

const preloadedState = loadStateFromLocalStorage();

const browserVersion = (preloadedState.version && preloadedState.version.current) || null;

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    Object.assign({}, preloadedState, {version: {latest: VERSION, current: browserVersion}}),
    middleware
);
```

I could then check in my `AppContainer` component (since it's the first component to mount after authentication) for the `latest` version versus the `current` version.

```
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(checkForUpdates());
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.dispatch(checkForUpdates());
    }
    render() {
        return <App {...this.props} />
    }
}
```

`checkForUpdates()` would prompt a modal that would indicate that the user must logout to continue. Logging out would set the entire state to `{version: {latest: VERSION, current: VERSION}}`.

---

This approach seems overly complicated in accomplishing what I'm attempting to accomplish, which is basically to (a) inform user of upgrade (b) log user out/purge state (c) load new, initial state from updated JS bundle.

Would this work and account for edge cases? Is this a reasonable way to accomplish persisting a version number to a state tree?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you have to do it in Redux? *[answer in comment]*

You could avoid the whole reducer and dispatch by using vanilla JS to compare the versions before performing the `ReactDOM.render`.

**UPDATE**:

Take a look at [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#why-redux-persist) and [redux-persist-migrate](https://github.com/wildlifela/redux-persist-migrate). I haven't used them but it's an abstraction over redux state persistance and migration.

Comment: I still want the DOM tree to reflect the current session and need to take advantage of items in the state tree, modal functionality, for example.